# How to call the game where you have to find where a picture was taken?

Tags: word-requests

In Japanese, is there a word or expression for the game where someone posts a picture of a place, and others have to find where it is, or even take the same picture?

If there is no specific word, what would be the shortest/easiest expression?

---

## Example:

*Where in Tokyo was this picture taken?* [image: pic]

Comment: I really would like to know if you have a short expression for that in French.

Comment: I don't know what to call it in English, either.  I looked online and found "mystery photo game" and "'where was this picture/photo taken?' game" :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about...

[「場所当てゲーム」](https://www.google.co.jp/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#newwindow=1&q=%22%E5%A0%B4%E6%89%80%E5%BD%93%E3%81%A6%E3%82%B2%E3%83%BC%E3%83%A0%22)

[「場所当てクイズ」](https://www.google.co.jp/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#newwindow=1&q=%22%E5%A0%B4%E6%89%80%E5%BD%93%E3%81%A6%E3%82%AF%E3%82%A4%E3%82%BA%22)

Comment: 「撮影場所当てクイズ」「写真場所当てクイズ」でもいいかと・・・